# Need a 240VAC logic OR gate

Tags: mains, logic-gates

Bit of background, we have an open office and there are toilet blocks in the office, sometimes you can hear sounds coming from the toilets, not to pleasant !

So I want to play the radio/music to drown out the unpleasant noises (powered ON inline with the lights) only problem is there are male and female toilets so I need to sense is the men’s light on or is the ladies lights on,I want to use a common music player

Is there an off the self solution for a high voltage logic OR gate ? Or do I need to do some custom engineering ?

Thanks

Comment: You can do this with relays. But how does the "or" function come into it? Do you want to do the same thing regardless of which bathroom light is on, or do you want to do something different in men's vs women's bathroom?

Comment: A diode from each light power wire can activate the radio. As energizing either light would energize the relay.

Comment: This is a photo sensor that closes contacts in low light where you want with light on.  This can be inverted with a relay and other methods.  https://www.amazon.ca/Woods-59408-Outdoor-Hardwire-Photocell/dp/B003Z4ECKC?source=googleshopping&locale=en-CA&tag=googcana-20&ref=pd_sl_8u7yepqehy_e

Comment: Surely those noise won't be coming from the ladies' toliets?

Answer (score 12):

You can just wire two 240VAC relays with one coil across each lamp and the normally open contacts in parallel. That will work even if you have the lights on a timer.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxPqWS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Functionally, that's all you need.

You may have to consult someone familiar with the electrical codes wherever you are in order to get an installation that measures up to requirements.